# What is the XPath for the following element?

Tags: python, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I need to find the XPath for the following element below:

```
<a> href="/resident/register/">Register another device </a>
```

I assumed the solution would be

```
$x("//*[contains(@href, 'resident/register')]")
```

But this has returned nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: "Any ideas?" You might want to check: [xpath-syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

Comment: It would depend on how the rest of the page is built. Either way, [Firefox can tell you](https://i.imgur.com/x3CLjei.png)

Comment: Hi @Sam1811x, try this `//a[text()='Register another device']` locator

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as "the" XPath for an element. You will typically want to choose an XPath expression that identifies the element uniquely within a document and that remains stable if there are minor changes to the document. The best choice of XPath is therefore very context dependent. But the reason yours has failed does seem to be that the `href` is not actually an attribute, it seems to have been mistyped.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is malformed.

Change

```
<a> href="/resident/register/">Register another device </a>
```

to

```
<a href="/resident/register/">Register another device </a>
```

then your XPath will work as expected.

If your HTML is fixed, then you'll have to adjust your XPath to test the element content rather than the `href` attribute content:

```
//a[contains(.,'resident/register')]
```

but, although this can select the malformed `a` element, it won't be clickable since it lacks a proper `href` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

To start with @kjhughes nailed one of the issue with the *HTML* i.e. *HTML is malformed*, as you must have tried to provide a correct HTML from your understanding.

The actual *HTML* I suppose is as follows:

```
<a href="/resident/register/">Register another device </a>
```

So an effective *XPath* for the element can be either of the following:

- *XPath:1*

  ```
  "//a[contains(@href, '/resident/register') and contains(.,'Register another device')]"
  ```
- *XPath:2*

  ```
  "//a[contains(@href, '/resident/register') and normalize-space()='Register another device']"
  ```